# Lost file when moving it to a "All My Files" Finder window

Tags: macos, finder

By mistake, I moved a file in to a Finder window that I previously did a search in, so it was open on "All My Files" which is not really a folder.  Yet when I moved the file in to this Finder window, the file disappeared from its original location.  Now when I search for the file I cannot find it..

What happened to it?

Comment: A great thing to do after a slip-up like that is CMD-z ( undo ).   You'd be surprised at how many instances undo can be used.  I know it doesn't help much now :(

Comment: Do you know the name of the file?

Comment: Yes I know the name of the file, I mentioned that I was searching for the file..

Comment: It took me a few times to replicate it.  The file I dropped into "All My Files" ended up in `~/Documents`. *Spotlight found it just fine*.

Comment: Thanks @ephsmith, I see the file there, I guess my spotlight isn't configured to search there...  Please make a answer so that I can mark it as correct!

Comment: Sometimes I hate apple..

Comment: This shouldn't have happened and I think it's a bug or unforeseen side-effect.  Undo is a good thing to have your hands remember though.  I use it all the time--closing the wrong tab in Safari., moving the wrong file.  When I make a mistake, CMD-z is usually the first thing I try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file most assuredly ended up in your home directory somewhere.  I was able to replicate your problem and the file I dropped there ended up in my `Documents` directory.

If you don't see it in `Documents`, try searching for the file by name with Spotlight. Lastly, if that doesn't work, try issuing the following command in Terminal.app:

```
find $HOME -name "filename"
```